# How much warnings in C to enable?

Tags: c, warnings

This is a tiny project of about 2000LOC. It is being compiled with `-Wall`. Now, I tried adding `-Wextra`. Two things happened:

- Some minor but valid warnings popped up, e.g. Comparing signed with unsigned
- Some minor but false warnings popped up, e.g. Unused function parameter.

Those functions implement agreed-upon prototypes. But the extra parameters are really not needed for now.

However the unfixable warnings pollute the build log and could hide a much more dangerous warning.

*Should the -Wextra be retained or removed? How can a compromise be made for the most robust code development in the future?*

Comment: if you know the argument is unused then just add it in a `(void)arg;` statement, this is a noop and will document that you don't use it but stops the compiler from shooting warnings

Comment: @ratchetfreak, please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nearly all warnings have workarounds to silence them in specific circumstances

- the unsigned vs. signed comparison means you need to double check the types
- unused parameter warnings can be silenced by adding a `(void)arg;` statement in the function, this is a noop and will document that the argument is unused

failing that you can surround the warning emitting code with `#pragma`s that disable and re-enable those warnings as needed

Comment: Why does the noop workaround work?

Comment: because it is idiomatic that it works for exactly this need (silence unused warnings)...

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to get rid of those harmless warnings, without also disabling the useful ones.

1. The `-Wall` and `-Wextra` warning options enable a whole bunch of warnings that can also be enabled/disabled individually. To avoid generating the 'unused parameter' warnings, you can use

   ```
   -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter
   ```
2. If it is only for a limited number of arguments in a limited number of functions that the 'unused parameter' warning is known to be spurious, you can suppress the warning on a case-by-case basis

   - Either by using the parameter, if only in a no-op statement like

     ```
     (void)arg;
     ```
   - Or, if you don't mind GCC-specific code, by adding the `unused` attribute to the relevant parameters

     ```
     void foo(int arg __attribute__((unused)) )
     { /* ... */ }
     ```